# Node.js static file security: What happens if hackers can control my bucket?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to Node.js and I have Node.js App with Vue. I use AWS S3 to server static JS file like `app.XXXX.js manifest.XXXX.js vendor.XXXXX.js`

So what is the security implication if a hacker can gain access to my S3 bucket and try to modify my static JS files?
Can they execute code on my main server?

Answer (score 1):

If you lose controle over your javascript files. Anything can be done with them.

If you load the files inside your node application (Ea import them or eval them or such)

So A important question is why are you serving code from a different location outside of your controle?

Would it. It be better to serve data files from s3 and serve code from your own controlled host (Ea load in JSON files from s3)